# Combinatorics, permutations. Books

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, permutations

I want to study about combinatorics, permutations. I don't need for complicated things, I only want to understand this notions very well and only the to try to study more complicated notions.

Can you indicate some books, online pdfs?

thanks :)

Comment: http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first exposure to combinatorics was *Mathematics of Choice*  by Niven.  It's intended as an initial introduction for high school students and  doesn't use any advanced math.  The book is out of print now, but you can get a PDF version (with DRM) or a print-on-demand copy from the MAA.
http://www.maa.org/publications/ebooks/mathematics-of-choice

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest Salman Khan's excellent [video tutorials](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability) on the matter. They are a great way to get you started on things.